# Is there a way to use valueForKey with NSPredicate in UITest?

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing, uitest

I have the following test helper function for my iOS UI tests:

```
func waitForElementToHaveKeyboardFocus(element: XCUIElement) {
    self.expectationForPredicate(NSPredicate(format:"valueForKey(\"hasKeyboardFocus\") == true"), evaluatedWithObject:element, handler: nil)
    self.waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5, handler: nil)
}
```

In my test I have:

```
let usernameTextField = app.textFields["Username"]
let passwordTextField = app.secureTextFields["Password"]
waitForElementToHaveKeyboardFocus(usernameTextField)
```

The test fails with the following error:

```
error: -[ExampleAppUITests.ExampleAppUITests testExampleApp] : failed: caught "NSUnknownKeyException", "[<_NSPredicateUtilities 0x10e554ee8> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key hasKeyboardFocus."
```

If I put a breakpoint in the test at the failure and manually call `valueForKey("hasKeyboardFocus")` on both the focused and unfocused fields I seem to get the correct behavior:

```
(lldb) po usernameTextField.valueForKey("hasKeyboardFocus")
    t =    51.99s     Find the "Username" TextField
    t =    51.99s         Use cached accessibility hierarchy for ExampleApp
    t =    52.00s         Find: Descendants matching type TextField
    t =    52.01s         Find: Elements matching predicate '"Username" IN identifiers'
▿ Optional<AnyObject>
  - Some : 1

(lldb) po passwordTextField.valueForKey("hasKeyboardFocus")
    t =   569.99s     Find the "Password" SecureTextField
    t =   569.99s         Use cached accessibility hierarchy for ExampleApp
    t =   570.01s         Find: Descendants matching type SecureTextField
    t =   570.01s         Find: Elements matching predicate '"Password" IN identifiers'
▿ Optional<AnyObject>
  - Some : 0
```

Is it possible to make `valueForKey` on a `XCUIElement` work with `NSPredicate` in a UI test?  Is there another elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your predicate is slightly off. Try changing it to the following:

```
NSPredicate(format: "hasKeyboardFocus == true"), evaluatedWithObject:element, handler: nil)
```

You don't need to pass in the `valueForKey` part when creating the predicate.

Comment: Great, that works!  Oddly though, I tried it in the debugger and it doesn't work: `error: <EXPR>:2:1: error: value of type 'XCUIElement' has no member 'hasKeyboardFocus'`.  Whereas other predicates with that syntax, e.g.: `NSPredicate(format: "hittable == true")` DO work in the debugger.  But `hasKeyboardFocus` only works with `valueForKey` in the debugger.  Weird.

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this, where you pass your statement for `valueForKey("")` as a closure to the method:

```
func waitForElementToHaveKeyboardFocus(statement statement: () -> Bool, timeoutSeconds: Int)
{
    var second = 0
    while statement() != true {
        if second >= timeoutSeconds {
            XCTFail("statement reached timeout of \(timeoutSeconds) seconds")
        }

        sleep(1)
        second = second + 1
    }
}
```

and then use in the test like:

```
waitForElementToHaveKeyboardFocus(statement: { usernameTextField.valueForKey("hasKeyboardFocus") as? Bool == true }, timeoutSeconds: 10)
```

you can rename this method to be more generic and it will validate your any closure passed into it. Hope this helps!